# Need a JQuery Timeline plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I love the timeline of this plugin, http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/ but I don't want the top section.

All I want is the bottom, stacked events, section and the ability to respond to a click event.

Does anyone know of one?

Comment: 15+ Memorable jQuery Timeline Plugins: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/jquery-timeline-plugins.html

Comment: Been there, done that.  But it's the look of the one i referenced that i am really after.  the others on that page don't really come close

Answer (score 0):

[Timeline JS](http://timeline.verite.co/) is all over the Internet the past few days, and may be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: seen this one but it again has the huge slide at the top which is not what i want.  i just want the timeline at the bottom.  i guess i could always hide the top slide